# OPC UA vs MQTT for internal interoperability

Tags: mqtt, protocols, interoperability

I am working on a project which will require networking with multiple IoT devices and sensors (scales, temperature sensors, actuated switches, etc.).

I am familiar with the MQTT architecture, while I have had just a surface exposure to OPC UA. From my understanding, OPC UA is more challenging to implement, so my question is: Are there any reasons while I should consider looking deeper into OPC UA?

Considering that:

- Publish-Subscribe vs Client-Server does not make much difference for my application.
- A key advantage of OPC UA seems to be standardisation for communication between devices, but my devices only need internal interoperability, they will not be exposed to third parties.
- I have no legacy devices, it's a greenfield project.

Comment: Some related (old) answers can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897654/opc-ua-protocol-vs-mqtt-protocol and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52074597/when-it-is-justified-to-use-ua-opc-and-ua-opc-architectures-over-mqtt?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: While useful, they do not address my specific situation of only needing to have IoT devices interoperate internally to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Pasting a response I received elsewhere:

> I don't see why you would go the OPC UA route, unless you need to
> integrate with an already existing OPC server. MQTT is light,
> reliable, and very easy to implement. If speed is not an issue for
> you, then i think we have a winner. If standardisation is what you are
> missing, consider using Sparkplug B. Take a look at what HiveMQ has to
> offer, but there are also others that deal with SpB.

Comment: To try it in real-time in minutes check out our https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/sparkplug .